# Laravel Nova How to display a resource with millions of rows?

Tags: large-data, laravel-nova

I have a resource with 5 million rows in an InnoDB table. Nova times out when executing a COUNT(*) query. I imagine this is used in pagination.  Is there a way to disable that behavior (just have a NEXT PREV in pagination) for only one particular resource?

The query it times out on is:

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `queue_articles`
```

I expect it to display the resource as a Nova resource index.

Comment: Using the `simple` pagination type can be inefficient for large datasets since it retrieves all the records from the database and applies the pagination in PHP